# Elasticsearch Field Preference for result sequence

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the index in elasticsearch with the following mapping:

```
{
    "test": {
        "mappings": {
            "documents": {
                "properties": {
                    "fields": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "uid": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "copy_to": [
                                    "fulltext"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "fulltext": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While searching I want to set the preference of fields for example if search text found in title or url then that document comes first then other documents.

Can we set a field preference for search result sequence(in my case preference like title,url,tags,fields)?

Please help me into this?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "boosting" . Prior to elasticsearch 5.0.0 - boosting could be applied in indexing phase or query phase( added as part of field mapping ). This feature is deprecated now and all mappings after 5.0 are applied in query time .

Current recommendation is to to use query time boosting.

Please read this documents to get details on how to use boosting:

1 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html

2 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How I can use this in a full-text search query (simple_query_string)?

Comment: yes, you can use by "^" notation (eg: termvalue^5 )